# Space inserted in front of % when updating from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 in Azure devops

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, string-interpolation

When I upgraded my build host from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04
the (interpolated) string formatting changed.
What was earlier `"{x:P0}"` => `"42%"`
is now `"42 %"`.

How can this happen?

The OS is only an... OS. There is no change to the pipeline, which still uses 3.1.x.
I am positive nothing else changed as I am using MSDevops and has commited and reverted again and has double checked no other change was made.

Comment: The `P0` format string is affected by culture settings, so yes, OS changes will have an effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`P0`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#PFormatString) format string is affected by culture settings, so yes, OS changes will have an effect.

For example, this code:

```
var x = 0.42;

Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("P0", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR")));
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("P0", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB")));
```

Will output:

```
42 %
42%
```

Comment: That is correct and forcing the culture would solve my GUI problem. But why would an OS update in Azure Devops result in culture change? When will it happen next time? I have ideas about Microsoft changing the culture of their docker images in the build pipeline depending site(?) region(?) and starting that behaviour after 16.04. I hope for someone to have dug into this to stroll by and answer.

Comment: .NET Core/5 takes its cultures from the OS so the upgrade may have changed the culture definition too.

Comment: Culture changed with the OS update. I have verified I am running dotnet v3.1.18 in both cases. With Ubuntu v16.0.4 the CurrentCulture is ["en-US", "en"] and with v18.0,4 it is ["" , "iv"]. Which is the right way to go imho.

Comment: DefaultThreadCurrentCulture and DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture have no Name or TwoLetterISOLanguageName and do not change.